# MacBook Pro 15" 2010 keyboard won't work in login screen - Yosemite

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I did an update to Yosemite yesterday, but today I turned the computer on and tried to type my password in. I couldn't because the keys I P A D K L M C don't seem to be working, I have tried three different keyboards and none work. Two of the keyboards are official Apple. I tried them in my windows laptop and all the keys are working fine. I then booted into the recovery on the MBP and I could type with all the keys. I thought it was fixed so restarted. I then had the exact same problem and am at a loss of what to do. I've tried Apple support, but they are about as useful as a chocolate tea pot. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

Start your Mac from the recovery partition. Once it's booted, go to the **Utilities** menu item and select **Terminal**. Type in the following command (substituting the OS X startup disk name if different from **Macintosh HD**)...

```
rm /Volumes/"Macintosh HD"/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist
```

...and then restart your MacBook.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, It says "No such file or directory" when I type this in..?

Comment: That's odd, the file *should* exist on that path (I tried it to confirm before posting the reply). Is your hard drive named as above? You only need to put in the quotes if there is a space in the title.

Comment: I have tried it again, but still get the same message, I checked and the disk is called Macintosh HD

Comment: Just as a sanity check, type **ls /Volumes/"Macintosh HD"/Library/Preferences** and see what happens. You should see a list of preference files if all is well...

Comment: Hmmm, "Command not found"...

Comment: There was a chance that would happen - did you type the "l" in "ls" as a capital "i"? It should be a lowercase "L" ;-)

Comment: I changed it to a lowercase L and it says "No such file or directory"

Comment: How about **ls /Volumes/**?

Comment: Says "Image Volume                     OS X Base System"

Comment: No **Macintosh HD** in the list? There certainly should be...

Comment: Nope :/ It comes up in Disk Utility though

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser. I presume you've run a disk check and verified permissions  with Disk Utility?

Comment: Yeah and all seemed fine

Comment: At this stage I'd be reaching for DiskWarrior to check the Catalog file - **Macintosh HD** should be visible in Terminal. If you have DW it's time to use it - if not then look for a copy of DW version 4.0-4.4, it can be obtained from a number of places. DW can (and does) find disk issues that Disk Utility either can't fix or isn't aware of. Unfortunately, without visibility of your Macintosh HD partition there's not much else I can offer, other than trying a **Safe Boot**, and as a final resort, running the Yosemite installer again.

Comment: I think I'm just gonna run the installer again (I understand that haha). Thanks a lot though, you have been very helpful!

Comment: One last thing to try (it's been a long day) is entering the following into Terminal **diskutil list**, then look for Macintosh HD in the result. Make a note of the disk identifier, it will be something like **/dev/disk0s2**. Once you know what it is, type in **diskutil mount /dev/disk0s2** (or whatever the disk identifier is for Macintosh HD). If successful you can go back up the page and try some of the commands that wouldn't previously work...

Comment: Turns out Macintosh HD was locked and encrypted, once I'd unlocked and decrypted it I tried the first command that you said and now it's working. Thank you so much, you are a Jedi...

Comment: Fantastic, I've learned something there too :-D